# GeoWebCache, GeoServer and Apache Architecture

Tags: geoserver, wms, geowebcache, apache, wmts

I'm configuring a new distributed GeoServer environment and I have some doubts about GWC Standalone, GeoServer & Apache architecture.

I have the following architecture set in a single developing machine.

```
Apache HTTPD **HTTP 80**
2 Geoserver Instances (2 TOMCAT) **HTTP 8080** **HTTP 8081**
1 GeoWebCache Standalone Instance (1 TOMCAT) **HTTP 8082**
```

I have a load balance configuration in Apache HTTPD with `mod_jk` that points to the 2 GeoServer instances. The 2 GeoServer Tomcat instances are clustered and point to a single DATA DIR.
I've also configured GeoWebCache DATA CACHE DIR.

If I make a request to http://localhost/geoserver it calls one of the 2 GeoServer instances.
If I make a request to http://localhost/geowebcache it calls the GeoWebcache instance (redirects to /geowebcache/home).
I've set the **WMS getCapabilites** URL from my Geoserver; at `geowebcache-core-context.xml`

Everything is working fine!

My first doubt is in concern to GeoWebCache and GeoServer WMS endpoints when consuming it in the front-end app (OpenLayers). What is the best approach when calling WMS service?

1. Make a URL rewrite with Apache so that I call `/geoserver/gwc/service/wms/...` and it would point to GeoWebCache instance
2. Call GeoWebCache URL directly: `/geowebcache/service/wms/...`
3. Make a URL rewrite to Geoserver WMS URL so that when I call `http://localhost/geoserver/<workspace>/wms/...` it would point to GeoWebCache instance

Second doubt is about the integrated GWC configuration.

- Should I disable GWC at GeoServer **Caching Defaults** configuration when using GWC standalone?
- What really happens when I enable **WMS-C**? Does it just enables `/geoserver/gwc/sevice/wms` URL?
- And what really happens when I enable **WMS direct integration**? Does it make `/geoserver/wms` URL call the integrated GWC?
- Do the configuration made in **Tile Caching** GeoServer panel of each layer affects GWC Standalone (is it passed at `getCapabilities`)?

The resources I've read on GWC Standalone aren't so clear in the docs. I hope someone have these answers.